# Add custom ID to wp_nav_menu list items

Tags: menus, navigation

Is it possible to assign specific ID's to `wp_nav_menu` list items?

For example, if my menu contained links for "Home", "About" and "Contact", could I assign the "Home" list item an ID of `home`?

Comment: You can by either using simple JavaScript/jQuery or by extending the menu walker class
and here is a nice example for that: _adding page id’s to menu_

Comment: The above comment was previously an answer to this question but it relied on a link that no longer works and did not contain the answer itself in its text. I've converted it into a comment for posterity as it gives useful hints to what the answer is, even if it no longer links to the answer